# fedex configuration in magento confusion in account id/key?

Tags: magento-1.9, fedex

I'm setting up in sandbox mode. The fields i have to fill in magento backend(Shipping method > FedEx)

> **Account ID**, **Meter Number**, **Key** & **Password**

Where as on signing up on FedEx developers account. I received mail [image]

and i have other account ID to login(Developers account) **ccgxxxxxxxxx**

My question here is which one here is Account ID and Key ?